# How to get src of original image instread of thumbnail in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have used this code to get the `img` `src` attribute:

```
$('.listpic').attr('currentSrc');
```

The image url is: `newyorkmodelhstn.jpg`. I have to remove `tn` from this to get the original img src. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this..

```
var imgs=document.getElementsByClassName("listpic"); 


for(var i=0;i< imgs.length;i++) 
{
var str=imgs[i].src;
var find='tn.';
var re=new RegExp(find,'g');
str=str.replace(re, '.');
var a = $("<a>").attr("href", str).attr("download", imgs[i].alt).appendTo("body");
a[0].click();
a.remove();  }
```

Answer (score 1):

first rename the string then access it:

```
var str="newyorkmodelhstn.jpg";
var find = 'tn.';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
str = str.replace(re, '.');//use this to get the image
alert(str);
```

or you can do this:

```
var str="newyorkmodelhstn.jpg";
str = str.replace("tn.", '.');//use this to get the image
```

visit this thread for good explanation and understanding:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: why the use of RegExp ? The only use case would be to get all occurences of `"tn."` which is obviously not what OP does want.

Comment: @Kaiido it can be done with normal replace also since he needs only one replacement.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, i add dot because a 'th' can be in a middle word

```
var str = 'newyorkmodelhstn.jpg';
var result = str.replace('tn.', '.');
```

Comment: in this case "tn" exactly placed in last. thanks any way